# Symfony 4.4 Unit Test - Cannot see dump() in tests that extend KernelTestCase and call self::bootKernel();

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

Using the example found here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing.html#unit-tests, combined with the example found here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html. In order to access the service container you have to extend `use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;` and call `$kernel = self::bootKernel();` in the `setUp()` function of the unit test.

However, when I extend this class and call `self::bootKernel()`, all ability to use `dump()` is lost, and when I call `print_r` or `var_dump` on any object that comes from say a query builder result, results in `killed.` in the console because it is too big so those are not an option when debugging entites and larger objects like dump is.

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Util;

use App\Util\Calculator;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class CalculatorTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }

    public function testAdd()
    {
        $calculator = new Calculator();
        $result = $calculator->add(30, 12);
        dump($result);

        // assert that your calculator added the numbers correctly!
        $this->assertEquals(42, $result);
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
$ php bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 7.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
^ 42
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 204 ms, Memory: 6.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Output with `self::bootKernel()` called:

```
$ php bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 7.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 471 ms, Memory: 16.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: There is no reason for your tests to have any output, though. You shouldn't be trying to echo or dump or do anything like that within testing.

Comment: For development purposes only, to make sure results are returning what I am expecting them to. They weren't, but I couldnt see that without the dump. I managed to get it working by using `$kernel = self::bootKernel(['debug' => 0]);`

Comment: @Emylee thanks it's work for me! ``'debug' => 0``

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
die(" Message From Test");
```

and if you want to print or show type of array or others
try to convert it to string by **json_encode**

```
json_encode(['name'=>"Test 1",'name'=>"Test 2",]);
```